# Customizable key generator for Node JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, private-key, public-key, keymanagement

I've been looking for a javescript/nodejs package that would take a passphrase as input and generate a public key. But I need it to produce the exact same public key with the exact same passphrase - meaning, based on what I've figured from my research, it needs to use the same salt and seed every time.

With that in mind, so far I haven't been able to find such a package. Pretty much all the packages I've found generate a random seed and a random salt every time they generate a new key, so they don't meet my needs. I did find [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet), but I run into an error when trying to run it - "can't find encStr of undefined". Here's the code:

```
var lightwallet = require("eth-lightwallet");
var salt = 'xgs7or/CAKh8I7cwhAicoXg1pBYXeouc+nzdVZ0PQXs=';
var secretSeed = 'category change resist inspire dove rocket hotel gadget return cream nut receive';
var x = "1234567890098765432112345678900987654321";

lightwallet.keystore.deriveKeyFromPasswordAndSalt(x, salt, function (err, pwDerivedKey) {var ks = new lightwallet.keystore(secretSeed, pwDerivedKey, "m/0'/0'/0'", salt); ks.isDerivedKeyCorrect(pwDerivedKey)})
```

Can you help me out? remember, I need it to produce the exact same public key when it's given the same passphrase.